# Inheriting from postgres docker container - doesn't keep the daemon alive?

Tags: docker

I'm writing a `Dockerfile` that pulls in an external dump, then loads it - https://github.com/scala-eveapi/postgres-sde/commit/95d2ed70dff8326c9acc75c56c9a7b8c8f6bbc73 - docker build works fine. When running it, it restored the DB, but after running the .sql, it just exits, instead of keeping the postgres server alive.

The file:

```
FROM postgres:latest
ADD https://www.fuzzwork.co.uk/dump/latest/postgres-20161114-TRANQUILITY.dmp.bz2 sde.bz2
# ADD postgres-20161114-TRANQUILITY.dmp.bz2 sde.bz2
RUN bunzip2 sde.bz2
COPY load-sde.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-load-sde.sh
COPY add-constraints.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/02-add-constraints.sql
```

The other two files are:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

pg_restore -d "${POSTGRES_DB:-$POSTGRES_USER}" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" sde
```

And the SQL:

```
alter table "mapSolarSystems"
alter column "solarSystemName" set not null;

alter table "invTypes"
alter column "typeName" set not null;

alter table "staStations"
alter column "stationName" set not null;

alter table "staStations"
alter column "solarSystemID" set not null;
```

Logs:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... 
WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start

****************************************************
WARNING: No password has been set for the database.
        This will allow anyone with access to the
        Postgres port to access your database. In
        Docker's default configuration, this is
        effectively any other container on the same
        system.

        Use "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set
        it in "docker run".
****************************************************
waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-12-06 12:05:18 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
done
server started
ALTER ROLE


/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-load-sde.sh
ERROR:  role "yaml" does not exist
STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE "agtAgentTypes" OWNER TO yaml;

[...] pg_restore errors

WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 89
```

Comment: No CMD or ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile, so the container stops, that is normal

Comment: Can you post logs from the container?

Answer (score 1):

The errors caused it to stop apparently. I added the `yaml` role and now it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last three lines on the initial Dockerfile (the one you're inheriting from: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/edd455e5b1dbfddc280beb244228054374f2f3dd/9.6/Dockerfile):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

You're extending that Dockerfile, but you're not setting the command to run... So yea, the container stops and it'll be marked as exited.

Comment: Added that, rebuilt, ran via `docker run <image id>`, still exits after running the pg restore.

Comment: @Reactormonk Have you added the `/docker-entrypoint.sh` file? You need to add it from here: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/edd455e5b1dbfddc280beb244228054374f2f3dd/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh to your project, otherwise `ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]` won't work